# Uncaught TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...).render is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript. I was trying to import jquery (`npm install jquery` in order to create an expandable navigation bar, however, after I downloaded it my project stopped loading. I tried to uninstall it (`npm uninstall jquery`), but I'm still not able to get my project to load. Now, I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...).render is not a function` error. I unsure why this is happening and would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to fix this problem.
Thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import store from './store';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Frontend package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.4",
    "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try clearing out the `node_modules` and re-installing... `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`

Comment: @Phil Hi, I tried doing that, but now I'm getting an ```Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"16.9.0" from react-native@0.61.5  node_modules/react-native
react-native@"^0.61.4" from the root project```. Also, ```npm start``` is not working. Instead, I'm getting ```sh: react-scripts: command not found```.

Comment: Did you do the `npm i` bit (aka `npm install`)?

Comment: @Phil No, I had only done ```rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json ``` and then tried  ```npm i```, and I've tried doing ```npm install``` and ```npm i``` again recently, and  it gave me:```Found: react@17.0.2  node_modules/react react@"^17.0.2" from the root project Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"16.9.0" from react-native@0.61.5 node_modules/react-native```.

Comment: Have you installed `react@16.9.0`? It's a peer dependency so won't automatically install. Perhaps you should add your `package.json` file to your question

Comment: @Phil Hi, I added my frontend package.json.

Comment: You need at least react-native v0.64 to use React v17. See https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/03/12/version-0.64#react-17

Comment: @Phil Okay, so I tried just updating react-native and that wasn't working, so I uninstalled and re-installed all of my dependencies, and now npm works again and npm start thankfully works again. Thank you for your help!